# How to group vector within a list?

Tags: r

```r
list <- list(
    z = c(a=30000,b=12,c=600,d=10),  
    x = c(a=30000,b=12,c=c(1600,1400,1400,1200),d=c(10,10)) )

$z
    a     b     c     d 
30000    12   600    10 

$x
    a     b    c1    c2    c3    c4    d1    d2 
30000    12  1600  1400  1400  1200    10    10
```

Expected output:

```
$x
    a     b             c                d 
30000    12  1600  1400  1400  1200    10  10
```

How to prevent the list from being subdivided into c1 c2 c3 c4 like what happened in x? is it possible to keep all values ​​within a single vector ??

## EDIT

it worked with this code below, but how do I create a generic function to apply as.numeric to each element of the list that is greater than 1?

```r
list<-list(
  z= c(a=30000,b=12,c=600,d=10),  
  x=c(a=30000,b=12,c=list(list(1600,1400,1400,1200)),d=list(list(10,10))))

list$x$c<-as.numeric(list$x$c)
list$x$d<-as.numeric(list$x$d)
```

Comment: Vectors can't contain other vectors like `list(x = c(y  = c(z = …)))`. For that you need to use another list, e.g. `list(x = list(y  = list(z = …)))`

Comment: Your edited code uses ```list(list())``` for ```x$c``` and ```x$d```.  Use ```list(c())``` instead and you'll immediately get the same final result, without needing the two calls to ```as.numeric```.

Comment: but, as a direct answer (and in case you need it in another situation), to apply ```as.numeric``` to all the elements of a list with a length greater than one, use: ```lapply(mylist,function(l) if(length(l)>1){as.numeric(l)}else{l})```

Comment: I didn't realize this error, your comment solved my problem, do you want to make your comment an answer?